# Java ArrayList made up of an abstract class and anything that extends it?

Tags: java, arraylist

I know this is a basic question, but I can't find other StackOverflow posts or any good API docs on this.

Say I have an abstract class like `Appliance` and then I have some classes like `Toaster` and `Blender` that extend `Appliance`. Now suppose that I want to create an ArrayList that will contain mixed elements, all of which are ultimately members of `Appliance` but could also be `Toaster` or `Blender` as well. The `Blender` class has a method called `turnBlenderOff()` and the `Toaster` class has a method called `turnToasterOff()`, and I will want to iterate over my ArrayList and call these methods, depending on which subclass the element actually belongs to.

Currently I make a class called `PowerPoint` and try:

```
 // Constructor given an ArrayList of appliances.
 public PowerPoint(ArrayList<Appliance> initial_list_of_appliances){
     int listSize = initial_list_of_appliances.size();
     for(int ii = 0; ii < listSize; ii++){
         this.applianceList.add(initial_list_of_appliances.get(ii));
     }
 }

 /////
 // Method to switch everything in the list OFF simultaneously.
 /////
 public void switchOff(){
     int N = this.applianceList.size();
     String cur_name;
     for(int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++){
         cur_name = this.applianceList.get(ii).getClassName();
             if(cur_name.equals("Blender")){
                 this.turnBlenderOff(this.applianceList.get(ii));
             }
             else if(cur_name.equals("Toaster")){
                 this.turnToasterOff(this.applianceList.get(ii)); 
             }
             else if(cur_name.equals("Oven")){
                 this.turnOvenOff(this.applianceList.get(ii));      
             }
         }
     }
```

Most of my code compiles fine, but I keep getting this error message:

```
 PowerPoint.java:83: turnBlenderOff(appliances.ApplianceWrapper.Blender) in PowerPoint cannot be applied to (appliances.ApplianceWrapper.Appliance)
      this.turnBlenderOff(this.applianceList.get(ii));
```

I see that this method, implemented to work only on `Blender` objects is trying to be executed on an `Appliance` object that happens to be a `Blender` but that the compiler doesn't realize this.

I tried to replace the `<Appliance>` type with `<? extends Appliance>` in the ArrayList specifications, but that gave additional errors and would not longer compile.

What is the proper way to make a list based on the abstract type, but then call methods of the subclassed type by using something like `getClassName()` to retrieve the subclass type?

**Added**

Since a lot of folks immediately pointed out the obvious: use inheritance better, I need to explain. For this project, we have to assume that all of the subclasses of `Appliance` were created by third-party people and put into some package that we cannot change. This was done in a bad, crufty way in which all different subclasses have different on/off methods and this can't be changed. So the option of designing a smooth `Appliance` abstract class is not open to me. For example, `Toaster` has the method `startToasting()`, while `Oven` has the method `heatUp()`, each of which serves as the 'on' method for the two different classes.

I think the exercise is meant to teach us: how would you retro-fit someone else's bad design job so as to minimize future damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) or [`getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html), not rolling your own `getClassName`, and then do an explicit cast to the type you just identified.

That said, prefer @guitarflow's answer, though that approach might not work if there is state that you can't just pass to the `switchOff` method.

Comment: My `getClassName()` is just a wrapper around the basic `Object` method `getSimpleName()`...

Comment: `Object` doesn't have a `getSimpleName` method.  Do you mean `getClass().getSimpleName()`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `class`. My synatx there is: `Toaster.class.getSimpleName()` for the `Toaster` subclass, for example.

Comment: Ah.  I'm still not convinced that's preferable to just doing it right there; I would do something like `if(appliance.getClass() == Toaster.class)`.

Comment: I think you're right. Coupling this with Ben Lawry's answer gives a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use an abstract class and all subclasses actually have the same functions, why don't you use a function in the abstract base class called "turnDeviceOff" and override it in the subclasses accordingly. That's the OO approach.

Comment: See my comment on Kent's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The ArrayList is ok.

but you could do this:

```
public abstract class Appliance{
 //declare an abstract method
abstract void switchOff();
}
```

then

```
public class Toaster extends Appliance{

//implement the abstract method
void switchOff(){
 //do toaster switchOff
}

}
```

for other subclasses, do the same.

finally,

```
for(Appliance element: yourList){
element.switchOff();
}
```

Comment: Exactly. That's the code to what I wrote below. That's the way to go!

Comment: This option is unfortunately removed from consideration. In my project, we have to assume that `Toaster`, `Blender`, etc. are all from some third party package, all implemented by different people, and all have their own crufty, different on/off methods. That's part of the point of the exercise.

Comment: @EMS is Appliance in 3rd party package too?

Comment: Yes. It's the 3rd party abstract class.

Comment: Ok, then I would compare the class or the name of the class. Although your example would be THE case to explain and use interfaces or abstract base classes! May you add methods to the 3rd party classes?

Comment: No, we can't modify them at all. I agree with you that we are being asked to do it this way specifically to teach us about proper inheritance. I can imagine people in the working world having to deal with this problem, though. Post-fitting something old and bad. I've had to do that with scientific algorithms before, but never with this sort of design idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do this.  The first (and *less-recommended*) way is by using the **instanceof** keyword and casting your **Appliance** instance into a **Blender** instance:

```
for(Appliance a : list){
    if(a instanceof Blender) this.turnBlenderOff((Blender)a);
    ...
}
```

This is bad because **instanceof** is slow and doesn't allow you to take advantage of Java's most powerful counterpart to polymorphism, **late binding**.  The better way would be to have the Appliance class have an abstract public method called *turnOff()*.  Then you could do something like:

```
for(Appliance a : list){
    a.turnOff();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're rather defeating the point of inheritance: `Appliance` should define a `turnOff()` method, which its children should implement appropriately for their needs.  That way you can just work with a list of `Appliance`s and not have to worry about what's what.

Otherwise, what's the point of them extending `Appliance` in the first place?

If you do need to figure out the type of something, use `instanceof`, testing class names as strings is a terribly brittle way of doing it.

#### Edit

Random style tip: it's almost never necessary to use index access on `List`s anymore:

```
public PowerPoint(List<Appliance> initialList){
   for(Appliance app : initialList)
     applianceList.add(app);
}
```

Of course there's also:

```
applianceList.addAll(initialList);
```

#### Edit 2

A more direct translation:

```
public void switchOff(){
    for(Appliance app : applianceList)
        switchOff(app);
}

private void switchOff(Appliance app){
    if(app instanceof Blender)
        turnBlenderOff(app);
    else if(app instanceof Toaster)
        turnToasterOff(app);
    else if(app instanceof Oven)
        turnOvenOff(app);
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("unknown appliance: " + app);
}
```

You could also add a wrapper around the different appliance classes that normalizes the API, but it may not be worth it (depending on how involved it is).

Comment: See my comment on Kent's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to solve is by adding a `turnOff()` method in Appliance class, and have the various subclasses override them appropriately. If you do that, then the big "if" code goes away.